# How to unbox a variable of type Any whose value can be Some(Some(value can be integer or string))

Tags: scala

I have a variable which can be None, or Some(None), Some(4), or Some(Some(4)). How can I unbox to get the value 4 or None if there is no value?

Comment: `variable.flatten` should do the job. However, having an **Option[Option[A]]** is usually a sign of a bad design _(there are valid use cases though)_. Probably you had a `map` where it should have been a `flatMap` instead.

Comment: variable can be None, or Some(4), or 4, or Some(Some(4)). Can we still do variable.flatten?

Comment: No, because then the variable is of type **Any** and you have a major design problem. I would suggest you expanding your question with details, specially why it may be all those things.

Comment: To clarify, this is not a Seq or List.. it is just a single variable of type Any

Comment: `Any` is anyway a bad design symptom

Answer (score 4):

This is close to what is being asked but returns `Option[Int]` in all cases:

```
def recFlatten(a: Any): Option[Int] =
  a match {
    case i: Int => Some(i)
    case Some(x) => recFlatten(x)
    case _ => None
  }
```

This will return `Some(i)` if the nested value is an `Int` or `None` otherwise.

If you really want to return the `Int` rather than `Some(Int)` then the result has to be `Any` which makes it trickier to process afterwards:

```
def recFlatten(a: Any): Any =
  a match {
    case i: Int => i
    case Some(x) => recFlatten(x)
    case _ => None
  }
```

This will return the `Int` value or `None`.